# Import a specific range of rows from excel into a SQL table

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper, import-from-excel

I am trying to import a range of 30000 rows out of the 55000 row in an excel sheet into a table for SQL developer. To import excel into the database, I usually right click on the table name and use the 'Data Import Wizard'. But the wizard does not include a way to select a range.
Is there a way to import data from an excel spreadsheet into SQL table using a range?
Thanks!

Comment: maybe copy selected rows to new file and import this new file? ;)

Comment: true! but i thought there would be a better way to do it.